I'm Trying to Determine Why my Evolution Function isn't Triggering the Battle Blurb
In my code, I have an evolution function and I have a battle blurb. The evolution works fine. The battle blurb works fine for every single other action. However, when I try to handle the battle blurb from the _checkEvolution function, everything works except for populating the battle blurb specifically for Evolution. It is spaghetti code that I'm working with in its' current state.
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class BattleServices {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> userNyxians;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> opponentNyxians;
  final Map<String, dynamic> userDetails;
  final String? battleId; // Add battleId to handle NPC battles with battleId
  late Map<String, dynamic> moveMultipliers;
  late Map<String, dynamic> nyxianDetails;
  late Map<String, dynamic> npcBattleData = {}; // Initialize with empty map
  List<String> _battleBlurb = [];
  bool _battleEnded = false;
  bool _endBattleTriggered = false;

  static bool _dataLoaded = false;
  static Map<String, dynamic>? _cachedNyxianDetails;
  static Map<String, dynamic>? _cachedMoveMultipliers;
  // static Map<String, dynamic>? _cachedNpcBattleData; // Cache for NPC data

  BattleServices({
  required this.userNyxians,
  required this.opponentNyxians,
  required this.userDetails,
  this.battleId, // battleId for NPC battles
}) {
  _initializeData(); // Properly await the loading process
}

Future<void> _initializeData() async {
  await _loadData(); // Ensure all relevant data is properly loaded
}


  List<String> get battleBlurb => _battleBlurb;
  bool get battleEnded => _battleEnded;

  Future<void> _loadData() async {
  if (!_dataLoaded) {
    try {
      // Load move multipliers and Nyxian details regardless of battle type
      await Future.wait([
        _loadMoveMultipliers(),
        _loadNyxianDetails(),
        if (battleId != null) _loadNpcBattleData(), // Load NPC battle data if battleId is not null
      ]);

      _dataLoaded = true; // Mark data as loaded
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error during data loading
    }
  } else {
    // Use cached data if already loaded
    if (_cachedNyxianDetails != null) {
      nyxianDetails = _cachedNyxianDetails!;
    }
    if (_cachedMoveMultipliers != null) {
      moveMultipliers = _cachedMoveMultipliers!;
    }
  }
}


Future<void> _loadNpcBattleData() async {
  try {
    // Load the NPC battle data from your JSON file
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/npc_battles.json');
    npcBattleData = json.decode(jsonString);
  } catch (e) {
    
    npcBattleData = {}; // Ensure it is at least an empty map
  }
}

  Future<void> _loadMoveMultipliers() async {
    try {
      String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/move_multiplier.json');
      final Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);
      moveMultipliers = {for (var item in jsonData['moves']) item['name']: item};
      _cachedMoveMultipliers = moveMultipliers;
      
    } catch (e) {
      
    }
  }

  Future<void> _loadNyxianDetails() async {
    try {
      String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/nyxians.json');
      final List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);
      nyxianDetails = {for (var item in jsonData) item['nyxian_id'].toString(): item};
      _cachedNyxianDetails = nyxianDetails;
    } catch (e) {
      
    }
  }

  



  Map<String, double> calculateStats(Map<String, dynamic> nyxian) {
  String nyxianId = nyxian['nyxian_id'].toString();

  // Load from nyxianDetails for both NPC and user battles
  var details = nyxianDetails[nyxianId] ?? npcBattleData['nyxian_types'].firstWhere(
    (type) => type['nyxian_id'].toString() == nyxianId,
    orElse: () => null,
  );

  if (details == null) {
    
    return {};
  }

  

  double level = nyxian['level'] is String
      ? _calculateNpcLevel(nyxian['level'], userNyxians)
      : nyxian['level'].toDouble();

  double atk = (details['atk'] ?? 10) * (1.2 * level) * ((nyxian['atk_x'] ?? 10) * 0.01 + 1);
  double def = (details['def'] ?? 10) * (1.2 * level) * ((nyxian['def_x'] ?? 10) * 0.01 + 1);
  double hp = (details['hp'] ?? 10) * (1.2 * level) * ((nyxian['hp_x'] ?? 10) * 0.01 + 1);
  double speed = (details['speed'] ?? 10) * (1.2 * level) * ((nyxian['speed_x'] ?? 10) * 0.01 + 1);

  // Log before buffs
  

  // Check for Sunlit, Celestial, and Inverse buffs
  final currentTime = DateTime.now();
  final hour = currentTime.hour;
  bool isDay = hour >= 5 && hour < 17;
  bool isNight = hour >= 17 || hour < 5;

  if (nyxian['sunlit'] == true && isDay) {
    atk *= 1.10;
    def *= 1.10;
    hp *= 1.10;
    speed *= 1.10;
  }

  if (nyxian['inverse'] == true && isNight) {
    atk *= 1.10;
    def *= 1.10;
    hp *= 1.10;
    speed *= 1.10;
  }

  if (nyxian['celestial'] == true) {
    atk *= 1.15;
    def *= 1.15;
    hp *= 1.15;
    speed *= 1.15;
  }

  // Log after buffs
  

  return {'atk': atk, 'def': def, 'hp': hp, 'speed': speed};
}




  double _calculateNpcLevel(String formula, List<Map<String, dynamic>> userNyxians) {
    var highestLevel = userNyxians.map((n) => n['level'] as int).reduce(max);
    var multiplier = double.tryParse(formula.split('*')[1]) ?? 1.0;
    return highestLevel * multiplier;
  }

  bool userGoesFirst(Map<String, dynamic> userNyxian, Map<String, dynamic> opponentNyxian) {
    var userSpeed = calculateStats(userNyxian)['speed']!;
    var opponentSpeed = calculateStats(opponentNyxian)['speed']!;
    return userSpeed >= opponentSpeed;
  }

  Future<void> performBattleAction(
  Map<String, dynamic> userNyxian,
  Map<String, dynamic> opponentNyxian,
  String? action, // Making this nullable to catch null values
  {bool forcedSwap = false}) async {
  
  // If action is null or empty, prevent the action from being performed
  if (action == null || action.isEmpty) {
    _battleBlurb.add("No valid move selected. Please choose a valid move.");
    _enableBattleButton(); // Re-enable the button to let the player take another action
    return;
  }

  if (_battleEnded) {
    return;
  }

  // Disable the battle button right away
  _disableBattleButton();
  _clearBlurb();

  // Forced swap should only be shown when the user's Nyxian faints, not the opponent's
  if (forcedSwap && userNyxian['currentHp'] <= 0) {
    _battleBlurb.add("${userNyxian['nyxian_name']} fainted. Please choose another Nyxian.");
    _enableBattleButton();  // Re-enable the button if forced swap happens
    return;
  }

  bool isUserTurn = userGoesFirst(userNyxian, opponentNyxian);

  // If the user goes first, process their action first
  if (isUserTurn) {
    await _executeAction(userNyxian, opponentNyxian, action);

    // Opponent takes a turn if they're still alive
    if (opponentNyxian['currentHp'] > 0 && userNyxian['currentHp'] > 0 && !_battleEnded) {
      await _opponentTurn(userNyxian, opponentNyxian);
    }
  } else {
    // Opponent goes first, and the user follows
    await _opponentTurn(userNyxian, opponentNyxian);

    if (userNyxian['currentHp'] > 0 && opponentNyxian['currentHp'] > 0 && !_battleEnded) {
      await _executeAction(userNyxian, opponentNyxian, action);
    }
  }

  // Check if the battle is over
  _checkBattleEnd();

  // Re-enable the button after everything finishes
  _enableBattleButton();
}






  Map<String, dynamic>? _cachedMoveData; // To cache move data
Map<String, dynamic>? _cachedActiveNyxian; // To cache active Nyxian

Future<void> _executeAction(
  Map<String, dynamic> activeNyxian, 
  Map<String, dynamic> targetNyxian, 
  String action
) async {
  // Add a short delay before performing the action to ensure data is ready
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

  try {
    // Ensure that the action string is not empty
    if (action.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception("Invalid action: action cannot be empty.");
    }

    // Check if the active Nyxian has changed
    if (_cachedActiveNyxian == null || _cachedActiveNyxian!['nyxian_id'] != activeNyxian['nyxian_id']) {
      _cachedActiveNyxian = activeNyxian;  // Update cached Nyxian
      _cachedMoveData = _loadMoveDataForNyxian(activeNyxian); // Load move data
    }

    // Use cached move data to execute action
    if (action == 'Heal') {
      performHeal(activeNyxian);
    } else {
      // Ensure that both activeNyxian and targetNyxian contain necessary data
      if (_cachedMoveData != null && activeNyxian.isNotEmpty && targetNyxian.isNotEmpty) {
        await performAttack(activeNyxian, targetNyxian, action);
      } else {
        throw Exception("Invalid data: Nyxian details or move data missing.");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    
    _battleBlurb.add("An error occurred while performing the action.");
  }
}

Map<String, dynamic> _loadMoveDataForNyxian(Map<String, dynamic> nyxian) {
  // Here, you would load the moves for the Nyxian and return them
  // This is just a placeholder implementation; you should implement actual move data retrieval.
  return {
    'move_1': nyxian['move_1'],
    'move_2': nyxian['move_2'],
    'move_3': nyxian['move_3'],
    'move_4': nyxian['move_4']
  };
}





  Future<void> performAttack(
  Map<String, dynamic> attacker, 
  Map<String, dynamic> defender, 
  String moveName
) async {
  _clearBlurb();  // Clear the previous blurb before the new action starts

  var attackStats = calculateStats(attacker);
  var defendStats = calculateStats(defender);

  var moveData = moveMultipliers[moveName];
  if (moveData == null) {
    _battleBlurb.add('Move $moveName is not found.');
    return;
  }
  // Generate the battle blurb right away
  _battleBlurb.add("${attacker['nyxian_name']} used $moveName!");
  
  // Allow the UI to render the blurb before proceeding
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); 

  // Attack logic
  int successRate = moveData['successRate'] ?? 100;

  if (Random().nextInt(100) + 1 > successRate) {
    _battleBlurb.add("${attacker['nyxian_name']} attacked with $moveName, but it missed!");
    return;
  }

  double multiplier = moveData['multiplier'];
  String moveType = moveData['moveType'];

  double damage = (attackStats['atk']! * multiplier) - (defendStats['def']! * 0.1);
  if (damage < defendStats['hp']! * 0.01) damage = defendStats['hp']! * 0.01;

  damage *= _getTypeEffectiveness(moveType, defender);

  // Critical hit check
  if (_isCriticalHit()) {
    damage *= 1.2;
    _battleBlurb.add("${attacker['nyxian_name']} dealt a critical hit of ${damage.round()} damage to ${defender['nyxian_name']}.");
  } else {
    _battleBlurb.add("${attacker['nyxian_name']} dealt ${damage.round()} damage to ${defender['nyxian_name']}.");
  }

  // Check effectiveness
  double effectiveness = _getTypeEffectiveness(moveType, defender);
  if (effectiveness > 1) {
    _battleBlurb.add("It's super effective!");
  } else if (effectiveness < 1) {
    _battleBlurb.add("It's not very effective.");
  }

  // Apply damage to defender
  defender['currentHp'] -= damage.round();
  if (defender['currentHp'] < 0) defender['currentHp'] = 0;

  // Handle defeat if the defender's HP reaches 0
  if (defender['currentHp'] == 0) {
    await _handleDefeat(defender, attacker);
  }
}




  Future<void> _opponentTurn(Map<String, dynamic> userNyxian, Map<String, dynamic> opponentNyxian) async {
  // If the user Nyxian's HP is 0 or below, skip the opponent's turn
  if (userNyxian['currentHp'] <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  bool shouldHeal = Random().nextDouble() < 0.15;
  
  // Determine if the opponent should heal or attack
  if (shouldHeal) {
    performHeal(opponentNyxian);
    _battleBlurb.add("${opponentNyxian['nyxian_name']} healed.");
  } else {
    var moves = ['move_1', 'move_2', 'move_3', 'move_4'];
    String randomMoveKey = moves[Random().nextInt(moves.length)];
    String? randomMove = opponentNyxian[randomMoveKey];

  

    // Ensure the move isn't null and exists
    if (randomMove != null) {
      try {
        await performAttack(opponentNyxian, userNyxian, randomMove);
      } catch (e) {
        _battleBlurb.add("The opponent failed to execute the move $randomMove due to an error: $e");
      }
    } else {
      _battleBlurb.add("The opponent failed to execute an attack because no valid move was found.");
    }
  }

  // If user Nyxian's HP reaches 0 after the attack, force a swap
  if (userNyxian['currentHp'] <= 0) {
    await _switchUserNyxian(userNyxian, forcedSwap: true);
  }
}





  Future<void> opponentTakesTurn(Map<String, dynamic> userNyxian, Map<String, dynamic> opponentNyxian) async {
    _clearBlurb();
    _battleBlurb.add("Opponent is taking their turn...");

    await _opponentTurn(userNyxian, opponentNyxian);

    if (userNyxian['currentHp'] > 0) {
      _battleBlurb.add("Opponent's action complete.");
    }

    _checkBattleEnd();
  }

  double _getTypeEffectiveness(String moveType, Map<String, dynamic> defender) {
    String defenderType1 = nyxianDetails[defender['nyxian_id'].toString()]['type_1'];
    String defenderType2 = nyxianDetails[defender['nyxian_id'].toString()]['type_2'];

    double multiplier = 1.0;

    if (_isWeakness(moveType, defenderType1) || _isWeakness(moveType, defenderType2)) {
      multiplier *= 1.3;
    }

    if (_isResistance(moveType, defenderType1) || _isResistance(moveType, defenderType2)) {
      multiplier *= 0.7;
    }

    return multiplier;
  }

  bool _isWeakness(String moveType, String defenderType) {
    var weaknesses = {
      'Ice': ['Fire', 'Electric', 'Dawn'],
      'Water': ['Electric', 'Toxic'],
      'Electric': ['Psy', 'Grass'],
      'Dawn': ['Dusk', 'Toxic'],
      'Dusk': ['Dawn', 'Psy'],
      'Ancient': ['Cyber', 'Insect'],
      'Cyber': ['Electric', 'Water'],
      'Grass': ['Fire', 'Insect'],
      'Psy': ['Insect', 'Toxic'],
      'Toxic': ['Ancient', 'Cyber'],
      'Insect': ['Fire', 'Psy'],
      'Fire': ['Water', 'Cyber'],
    };
    return weaknesses[moveType]?.contains(defenderType) ?? false;
  }

  bool _isResistance(String moveType, String defenderType) {
    var resistances = {
      'Ice': ['Water', 'Psy'],
      'Water': ['Fire', 'Ice'],
      'Electric': ['Water', 'Cyber'],
      'Dawn': ['Ice', 'Grass'],
      'Dusk': ['Ancient', 'Cyber'],
      'Ancient': ['Psy', 'Grass'],
      'Cyber': ['Dawn', 'Fire'],
      'Grass': ['Water', 'Psy'],
      'Psy': ['Ancient', 'Dawn'],
      'Toxic': ['Water', 'Grass'],
      'Insect': ['Grass', 'Ancient'],
      'Fire': ['Ice', 'Grass'],
    };
    return resistances[moveType]?.contains(defenderType) ?? false;
  }

  bool _isCriticalHit() {
    return Random().nextDouble() < 0.15;
  }

  Future<void> _handleDefeat(Map<String, dynamic> defeatedNyxian, Map<String, dynamic> victorNyxian) async {
  double oldMaxHp = calculateStats(defeatedNyxian)['hp']!;
  double expGained = oldMaxHp * 0.2;

  // Ensure exp gained is positive
  if (expGained < 0) {
    expGained = 0;
  }

  // Check if the victorious Nyxian belongs to the user
  if (userNyxians.contains(victorNyxian)) {
    // Update main Nyxian's EXP and handle level-up immediately
    await _updateExpAndCheckLevelUp(victorNyxian, expGained.round());

    _battleBlurb.add("${victorNyxian['nyxian_name']} has gained ${expGained.round()} EXP.");

    // Check for Equinox Shard
    if (victorNyxian['item'] == 'Equinox Shard') {
      double sharedExp = expGained * 0.3;
      _battleBlurb.add("Your other Nyxians got ${sharedExp.round()} EXP.");

      // Distribute shared EXP to other Nyxians in the roster
      for (var nyxian in userNyxians) {
        if (nyxian != victorNyxian && nyxian['currentHp'] > 0) { // Ensure not giving EXP to fainted Nyxian
          await _updateExpAndCheckLevelUp(nyxian, sharedExp.round());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Handle defeat depending on whether the user's or opponent's Nyxian was defeated
if (userNyxians.contains(defeatedNyxian)) {
  // User's Nyxian was defeated
  await _switchUserNyxian(defeatedNyxian, forcedSwap: true);
} else {
  // Opponent's Nyxian was defeated
  _battleBlurb.add("${defeatedNyxian['nyxian_name']} was defeated.");
  await _switchOpponentNyxian(defeatedNyxian);

  // Check for evolution after the opponent's defeat
  for (var nyxian in userNyxians) {
    await checkEvolution(nyxian);
  }
}
  }

// Helper function to update EXP and handle level-up
Future<void> _updateExpAndCheckLevelUp(Map<String, dynamic> nyxian, int expGained) async {
  // Update EXP in Firestore
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('captured_nyxians')
      .doc(nyxian['id'])
      .update({'exp': FieldValue.increment(expGained)});

  // Calculate new total EXP and level
  int newExp = nyxian['exp'] + expGained;
  int newLevel = calculateLevel(newExp);

  // Handle level-up if the new level is greater than the current level
  if (newLevel > nyxian['level']) {
    nyxian['level'] = newLevel;
    _battleBlurb.add("${nyxian['nyxian_name']} leveled up to $newLevel!");

    // Update the level in Firestore
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('captured_nyxians')
        .doc(nyxian['id'])
        .update({'level': newLevel});

    // Update max HP and current HP proportionally based on the new level
    double oldMaxHp = nyxian['max_hp'];
    double newMaxHp = calculateStats(nyxian)['hp']!;
    double hpRatio = nyxian['currentHp'] / oldMaxHp;
    nyxian['currentHp'] = (newMaxHp * hpRatio).round();
    nyxian['max_hp'] = newMaxHp.round();

    // Ensure current HP does not exceed max HP
    if (nyxian['currentHp'] > nyxian['max_hp']) {
      nyxian['currentHp'] = nyxian['max_hp'];
    }

    // Update HP values in Firestore
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('captured_nyxians')
        .doc(nyxian['id'])
        .update({
      'currentHp': nyxian['currentHp'],
      'max_hp': nyxian['max_hp'],
    });
  }
}


Future<void> _switchUserNyxian(Map<String, dynamic> defeatedNyxian, {bool forcedSwap = false}) async {
  bool hasAliveNyxian = userNyxians.any((nyxian) => nyxian['currentHp'] > 0);

  if (hasAliveNyxian) {
    _battleBlurb.add("${defeatedNyxian['nyxian_name']} has been defeated. Please choose your next Nyxian.");

    if (forcedSwap) {
      return;
    }
  } else {
    _endBattle(false); // User has no more Nyxians left
  }
}

Future<void> checkEvolution(Map<String, dynamic> nyxian) async {
  try {
    // Load nyxians.json if not already loaded or cached
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('json/nyxians.json');
    List<dynamic> nyxiansData = json.decode(jsonString);

    // Define evolution conditions in a list
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> evolutionConditions = [
      {'nyxian_id': 1, 'level': 250},
      {'nyxian_id': 2, 'level': 800},
      // Add more conditions here
    ];

    // Check if the current Nyxian meets any evolution condition
    for (var condition in evolutionConditions) {
      if (nyxian['nyxian_id'] == condition['nyxian_id'] && nyxian['level'] >= condition['level']) {
        int newNyxianId = nyxian['nyxian_id'] + 1;

        // Get the old and new Nyxian details from nyxians.json
        var oldNyxian = nyxiansData.firstWhere((nyx) => nyx['nyxian_id'] == nyxian['nyxian_id'], orElse: () => null);
        var newNyxian = nyxiansData.firstWhere((nyx) => nyx['nyxian_id'] == newNyxianId, orElse: () => null);

        // Check for missing data
        if (oldNyxian == null || newNyxian == null) {
          _battleBlurb.add("Error: Unable to find evolution details for Nyxian ID ${nyxian['nyxian_id']}.");
          return;
        }

        // Handle naming logic
        String finalName = newNyxian['name'];
        if (nyxian['celestial'] == true) {
          finalName = 'Celestial $finalName';
        } else if (nyxian['sunlit'] == true) {
          finalName = 'Sunlit $finalName';
        } else if (nyxian['inverse'] == true) {
          finalName = 'Inverse $finalName';
        }

        // Update Nyxian's ID and name
        nyxian['nyxian_id'] = newNyxianId;
        nyxian['nyxian_name'] = finalName;

        // Add evolution message to battle blurb
        _battleBlurb.add("Your ${oldNyxian['name']} evolved into a ${newNyxian['name']}!");

        // Optionally update in Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('captured_nyxians').doc(nyxian['id']).update({
          'nyxian_id': newNyxianId,
          'nyxian_name': finalName,
        });

        // Allow the UI to render the blurb
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

        break; // Evolution done, no need to check further conditions
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Catch any exceptions and add to battle blurb
    _battleBlurb.add("An error occurred during evolution: $e");
  }
}






Future<void> _switchOpponentNyxian(Map<String, dynamic> defeatedNyxian) async {
  int index = opponentNyxians.indexOf(defeatedNyxian);

  if (index + 1 < opponentNyxians.length) {
    var nextNyxian = opponentNyxians[index + 1];

    // Ensure next Nyxian's current HP is initialized
    if (!nextNyxian.containsKey('currentHp')) {
      nextNyxian['currentHp'] = calculateStats(nextNyxian)['hp']!;
    }

    // Add blurb for the new Nyxian being sent out
    _battleBlurb.add("${nextNyxian['nyxian_name']} was sent out!");

    // You can add any other logic here for setting the next Nyxian to be the active one
  } else {
    // If no more opponent Nyxians are left, end the battle
    _endBattle(true);
  }
}



  Map<String, dynamic>? getNextUserNyxian(Map<String, dynamic> currentNyxian) {
    int index = userNyxians.indexOf(currentNyxian);
    if (index + 1 < userNyxians.length) {
      return userNyxians[index + 1];
    }
    return null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic>? getNextOpponentNyxian(Map<String, dynamic> currentNyxian) {
    int index = opponentNyxians.indexOf(currentNyxian);
    if (index + 1 < opponentNyxians.length) {
      return opponentNyxians[index + 1];
    }
    return null;
  }

  void _endBattle(bool userWon) async {
  // Prevent multiple executions of end battle logic
  if (_endBattleTriggered) return;

  // Set the trigger flag to true to prevent further calls
  _endBattleTriggered = true;

  String opponentUsername = 'the opponent';

  // Retrieve opponent's username based on battle type
  if (battleId != null) {
    // Ensure npcBattleData is loaded before accessing
    if (npcBattleData.isEmpty) {
      await _loadNpcBattleData();
    }

    opponentUsername = npcBattleData['battles']
        .firstWhere((battle) => battle['id'] == battleId, orElse: () => null)?['username'] ?? 'the opponent';
  } else {
    // For `user_id` battles, default to "your opponent"
    opponentUsername = 'your opponent';
  }

  // Generate the appropriate battle end message
  if (userWon) {
    _battleBlurb.add("You've defeated $opponentUsername.");

    // Calculate money earned
    int totalMaxHp = opponentNyxians.fold(0, (sum, nyxian) => sum + calculateStats(nyxian)['hp']!.toInt());
    int moneyEarned = (totalMaxHp * 0.1).round();

    _battleBlurb.add("You earned $moneyEarned money!");

    try {
      // Find the document ID for the user
      QuerySnapshot userQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('user_id', isEqualTo: userDetails['user_id'])
          .limit(1)
          .get();

      if (userQuery.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        String documentId = userQuery.docs.first.id;

        // Update the logged-in user's money in Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(documentId)
            .update({'money': FieldValue.increment(moneyEarned)});
      } else {
        _battleBlurb.add("Failed to update money: user document not found.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle any potential errors during Firestore query/update
      
      _battleBlurb.add("An error occurred while updating money.");
    }
  } else {
    _battleBlurb.add("You were defeated by $opponentUsername.");
  }

  // Ensure that the battle blurb is updated before concluding the battle
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Allow UI to update

  if (userWon && battleId == 'evo') {
  for (var nyxian in userNyxians) {
    await checkEvolution(nyxian);
  }
  // Ensure battle blurb updates are complete before ending battle
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)); 
}


  // Mark battle as ended only after blurb updates
  _battleEnded = true;
}












  void performHeal(Map<String, dynamic> nyxian) {
    double maxHp = calculateStats(nyxian)['hp']!;
    double healAmount = maxHp * 0.3;
    nyxian['currentHp'] += healAmount.round();
    if (nyxian['currentHp'] > maxHp) nyxian['currentHp'] = maxHp.round();
    _battleBlurb.add("${nyxian['nyxian_name']} healed for ${healAmount.round()} HP.");
  }

  int calculateLevel(int exp) {
    if (exp <= 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (1.25 * pow(exp, 1 / 3)).ceil();
    }
  }

  void _checkBattleEnd() {
  if (_battleEnded || _endBattleTriggered) return; // Prevent checking end conditions if already triggered

  if (userNyxians.every((nyxian) => nyxian['currentHp'] <= 0)) {
    _endBattle(false);
  } else if (opponentNyxians.every((nyxian) => nyxian['currentHp'] <= 0)) {
    _endBattle(true);
  }
}





  void _clearBlurb() {
    _battleBlurb.clear();
  }

  bool isButtonEnabled = true; // Track button state

void _disableBattleButton() {
  // You can implement this in your UI code to disable the button
  isButtonEnabled = false;
  // Trigger UI update if necessary, e.g., setState() in Flutter
}

void _enableBattleButton() {
  // Re-enable the button after the action is complete
  isButtonEnabled = true;
  // Trigger UI update if necessary, e.g., setState() in Flutter
}

}


I attempted to build the full evolution function into the endBattle function at one point so that it might just handle them as a part of the endBattle. When I did that, I attached it above the money blurb and action and all battle blurbs that occurred from the evolution onward stopped triggering.
